# iOS8 SKStoreProductViewController completion block not called

Tags: ios8, xcode6, storekit

I've found that running on iOS 8 devices (real devices):

```
[storeProductViewController loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:appID} completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
    // In many cases we never get here!
}];
```

I have a valid app ID. It works consistently on iOS7, but is extremely flaky on iOS8. There doesn't seem to be a timeout, it just never shows the content.

Is anyone else seeing this? Do you have a solution?

Comment: I have the same issue in iOS8. Works like charm in iOS7.

Comment: Same issue and have no solution. Retrieving the store content seems to take longer, or even no response at all, on iOS 8 then iOS 7 which is quite strange..

Comment: For us it seems flaky on a per-device basis. Some devices running 8.0.2 exhibit this frequently, others never do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Maybe your apple ID doesn't allow buying products on store, containing specific product? In my case, I've tried to show products from american iTunes, but account is set up to russian iTunes store.

For catching this situation try to do next steps:

1. Open itunesconnect, do to Users and Roles --> Sandbox Testers, then Create test user in accordance with specific iTunes Store country.

[image: itunesconnect, Users and Roles screen]

2. Log out from your apple account on mobile device.
3. Sign in with test apple account
4. Restart your app and try to open product with SKStoreProductViewController.

PS: Apple StoreKit is still headache for developers... Without correct error logging (((

Comment: I was already using a test account when running into this problem.

Comment: My problem has been resolved, when I changed user according to iTunes Store region. Maybe your situation is different